# My Query is too slow

Tags: mysql

My query that I made is too slow. It takes more than one minute. How can I quickly create a query?
Can you help me?

```
select * from nss_sikdan_ok where od_id in(
  select od_id from nss_order od 
  join nss_cart ct on od.on_uid=ct.on_uid 
  where ct.ct_status in('cart','sell')) and (DATE_FORMAT(today_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')='2017-05-05') and today_end='1' limit 0,1
```

Comment: https://tools.percona.com/query-advisor/PTBJITIG/advise paste your query here to get some overall idea and tips for optimization

Comment: Please share more details, like the execution plan for that query

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to optimize this query.

On the query side:

***Avoid calling functions on potentially indexed columns*** - as it won't allow MySQL to use the index on that column. The following condition:

```
DATE_FORMAT(today_end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')='2017-05-05'
```

Can be modified to this one, to avoid using the DATE_FORMAT function on the indexed column and instead only use functions on constant values:

```
today_end_date >= DATE('2017-05-05') AND today_end_date < (DATE('2017-05-05') + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

====

**Do not use OFFSET values in your query** - Instead of LIMIT X,Y, you can use the alternative approach for [faster pagination with offset in MySQL](https://www.eversql.com/faster-pagination-in-mysql-why-order-by-with-limit-and-offset-is-slow/).

===

**Avoid selecting unused columns** - in most cases, selecting all columns using the '*' operator will cause performance issues, as you're fetching more information than you actually need. Think about which columns you actually need in the result set and fetch them.

===

**Use numeric values whenever appropriate** - When comparing a numeric column to a string, you're forcing MySQL to cast the column's value for each row from a number to a string and only then perform the comparison. Therefore, in the condition today_end='1', if today_end is a numeric column, the condition should be:

```
today_end = 1
```

Instead of:

```
today_end = '1'
```

===

Also, if you can provide the schema structure, it will be possible to recommend the appropriate indexes for this situation.

By the way, I got the recommendations from this [online MySQL query optimizer](https://www.eversql.com), so feel free to just enter your query and schema there and get indexing recommendations as well.